# Installation issue in Nativescript

Tags: npm, nativescript, node-modules

Hi I am using Mintos(Linux) platform. For create Andriod app Angular based  using Nativescript so i installed Nativescript successfully installed node.js version 8.10.0. When i tried to install nativescript cmd `npm install -g nativescript` It was showing error like

```
mint2@mint2-ASAG3730-ASAG1730:~$ npm install -g nativescript
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
    /usr/local/lib
    +-- nativescript@5.1.0 
    `-- rc@1.2.7 
      `-- minimist@1.2.0 

    npm WARN tsutils@2.29.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >= 3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev but none was installed.
    npm WARN tslint@5.4.3 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev but none was installed.
    npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "nativescript"
    npm ERR! node v8.10.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
    npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno -13
    npm ERR! syscall access

    npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript'
    npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript'
    npm ERR!   errno: -13,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
    npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/mint2/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4):

npm does not have the necessary permissions to install nativescript:

> EACCES: permission denied, ...

From the [nativescript installation](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/quick-setup#step-2-install-the-nativescript-cli) notes:

> If you’re on macOS and receive an **EACCES error**, you either need to rerun the previous command with `sudo` — that is, **`sudo npm install -g nativescript`** — or take a moment to [fix your npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) so that you don’t need admin rights to globally install npm packages.

Comment: Please don't use sudo. Installing random code off the internet with admin rights is a bad idea.

Comment: It looks like the install script wants to write to /usr/local/. What's your alternative? Change permissions in /usr/local? Change the installation destination?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo npm install nativescript -g --unsafe-perm
```

Source: https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-linux

Answer (score -1):

you need to be root to install sir `sudo npm i -g nativescript@latest` to write to /user/local which is a protected directory

Answer (score -1):

To avoid all these kinds of problems on Linux, the best solution that I've found is to use Node Version Manager.

You can install it using:

`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`

**Logout and log back in again for the path updates to take effect.**

After this, see what Node versions are available:

`nvm list-remote`

Pick a version and install it, for example:

`nvm install v12.3.1`

nvm will automatically use this version (or whatever other version you selected).

You can install other versions as required and switch between versions using (for example):

`nvm use v12.3.0`

The advantages of doing things this way are at least the following:

- No more access control issues
- You can swap between Node versions as you please

Here's a repo link for further information: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score -1):

Im using Windows 10

and it works when you put a force on your command like this:

```
npm install -g nativescript -f
```

Hope it helps
Regards Atif